# Constructor Inheritance getting fatal error on new object

Tags: java, constructor

I have 3 classes: administrator, salaried employee, and employee. Administrator extends from salaried employee and that extends from employee. Here are their default constructors:

Employee:

```
public class Employee
{
private String name;
private Date hireDate;

public Employee( )
{
     name = "No name";
     hireDate = new Date("Jan", 1, 1000); //Just a placeholder.
}

/**
 Precondition: Neither theName nor theDate is null.
*/
public Employee(String theName, Date theDate)
{
    if (theName == null || theDate == null)
    {
         System.out.println("Fatal Error creating employee.");
         System.exit(0);
    }
    name = theName;
    hireDate = new Date(theDate);
}

public Employee(Employee originalObject)
{
     name = originalObject.name;
     hireDate = new Date(originalObject.hireDate);
}


}
```

SalariedEmployee:

```
public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee
{
private double salary; //annual

public SalariedEmployee( )
{
    super( );
    salary = 0;
}

/**
 Precondition: Neither theName nor theDate are null; 
 theSalary is nonnegative.
*/
public SalariedEmployee(String theName, Date theDate, double theSalary)
{
     super(theName, theDate);
     if (theSalary >= 0)
         salary = theSalary;
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Fatal Error: Negative salary.");
         System.exit(0);
     }
}

public SalariedEmployee(SalariedEmployee originalObject )
{
     super(originalObject);
     salary = originalObject.salary;
}

}
```

Administrator:

```
//Create a test program that uses scanner so person can input values for the admin class. 
public class Administrator extends SalariedEmployee
{
private String title;
private String responsibility;
private String supervisor;

//No argument Constructor
public Administrator( )
{
    super( );
    title = "No Title";
    responsibility = "No Responsibility";
    supervisor = "Dilbert";
}

//3 argument constructor
public Administrator(String theTitle, String theResponsibility, String theSupervisor)
{
     super( );
     if (theTitle == null || theResponsibility == null || theSupervisor == null)
     {
          System.out.println("Fatal Error creating employee.");
          System.exit(0);
     }
     title = theTitle;
     responsibility = theResponsibility;
     supervisor = theSupervisor;
}

//6 argument Constructor
public Administrator(String theName, Date theDate, double theSalary, String theTitle, String theResponsibility, String theSupervisor)
{
     super(theName,theDate,theSalary);
     title = theTitle;
     responsibility = theResponsibility;
     supervisor = theSupervisor;
}

}
```

I try to create a new administrator object using:

```
Administrator admin = new Administrator();
```

But I get a fatal error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post the error if we're going to help you.

Comment: Usually no needed to call super(). By default it is called when you create a object.

Comment: I'm guessing `hireDate = new Date("Jan", 1, 1000);` could be the problem if that's `java.sql.Date` or `java.util.Date` since it expects `Date(int year, int month, int day)`. But need more information about his "error"

Comment: I guess that's another problem I'm having. I'm using eclipse right now and all I see when attempting to run the program is "fatal error".

Comment: "Fatal error" doesn't really tell us much. Does it compile? Is there a stack trace in the console?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob. Here's an image of what I mean. Is there a setting I need to change to show the actual error?
[link](http://snag.gy/GHhGr.jpg)

Comment: I think you should post your full classes: `Employee`, `SalariedEmployee`, and `Administrator`. Would make it easier to see what's wrong or see if we can reproduce it.

Comment: I posted the classes, but there is also a date.java file that it uses to create date objects. It does not use the one provided by java.util.date.

Comment: @user3002486: You've posted way too much code. (I realize that  user1071777 said to "post your full classes", but what you really need to post is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Here is the date.java file (sorry for double post): [link](http://pastebin.com/kFSce2dC)

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce it now that I have that Date class.

Comment: @Ruakh I edited the code so they only show constructors. Not really sure what too much code means as he wanted to reproduce the error.

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me. If I were you, I'd refresh my IDE, perhaps even exit out and restart it, and try to re-run it.

Comment: @user3002486: I *told* you what "too much code" means, and gave you a link to more helpful documentation. You shouldn't lop off code that's necessary in order to reproduce your problem; rather, you should trim your program to remove everything that's *not* needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ruakh: I disagree. The original poster was just doing as requested, and it was not an excessive amount of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Date class outputs "Fatal Error" everywhere in an non-informative way (which we had no idea of until you posted your Date class code).

The first time you get Fatal Error is inside the `setDate` method because `dateOK` returned false for `"Jan", 1, 1000`.

Your `monthOK` method is expecting `"January"`, so the `"Jan"` you're using for your default constructor is invalid. Change your default constructor to use

```
hireDate = new Date("January", 1, 1000);
```